# Creating Global Groovy Closure

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm trying to learn how to create a global closure in groovy (like the println closure).  I have the following code:

**a.groovy**

```
def header = Tools.&header
header 'groovy script a'
```

**b.groovy**

```
def header = Tools.&header
header 'groovy script b'
```

**tools.groovy**

```
class Tools {
    def static header(String str) {
        println("\n${str}")
        println("-" * 80)
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid:

```
def header = Tools.&header
```

in every groovy script where I would like to use the Tools.header() (and just use header closure when I import the tools package).  I tried to put the definition after the Tools class, but that did not work.  Can this be done?  Is there a better way to handle this?

---

**EDIT:** (using a metaClass and the evaluate method unless there is a simpler way to include an external script):

**a.groovy**

```
evaluate(new File("Tools.groovy"))
header 'groovy script a'
```

**b.groovy**

```
evaluate(new File("Tools.groovy"))
header 'groovy script b'
```

**tools.groovy**

```
Object.metaClass.header = {str ->
    println("\n${str}")
    println("-" * 80)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`println` is not actually a global closure. It's a method that is added to `java.lang.Object` using groovy metaprogramming. Because all classes extend `Object` - including the script class that wraps code run in the groovy console - `println` can be called from anywhere.

You can add your own methods to `Object`. Run this code in the Groovy console to see it in action:

```
// Add a global sayHello() method
Object.metaClass.sayHello = {-> println 'hello' }

// Try it out
sayHello()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I did need to add something like this to my scripts though: `evaluate(new File("../tools/Tools.groovy"))` to include the object.metaClass definition from one external script file into the other scripts.  It's a kind of pseudo "include" (maybe not the correct terminology, but what it looked like to me conceptually)

Answer (score 0):

`import static Tools.header` should do the trick. You don't need a closure in this case as you call simple method. If you'll have to pass `header` as a closure somewhere in your code of `a.groovy` or `b.groovy` the `&header` still could be used.